# PHP : Does extending class need another 'use' to call namespace?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, namespaces, extend

I'm wondering whether in the situation where I'm extending a class that has already 'use' keyword above it to use specific namespace - do I need to add another 'use' above the inheriting class to use the same namespace? Situation like this:

```
namespace Core;

use System\Plugin;

class Front extends Application { }
```

and now in the Controller, which is called directly without the namespace (using full path):

```
use System\Plugin;

class PageController extends Front { }
```

or would it work without 'use' as well and allow me to use the System\Plugin namespace:

```
class PageController extends Front { }
```

?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, you need the "use" statement in both files. Use is a file-level keyword and isn't affected by inheritance.

See the [scoping rules for importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and the little box describing what I said at the bottom of the manual page.

Comment: Obviously if within the Front class I've instantiated an object from within the Plugin namespace then I can use it without the 'use System\Plugin' in the inherited class.

Comment: Of course, and you don't always need a use statement either. Using the fully-qualified namespace works as well.

Comment: It'd be nice (i.e. DRYer) if classes could inherit `use` statements from parent classes