# Came back to a Laravel project that I hadn't touched in months and received a "compact(): Undefined variable: operator" error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving this error whenever I attempt to visit a certain view. Sadly the error doesn't make it any clear why is this happening. The project worked fine a month ago and I don't think I've made any changes since then but when I checked it out today, I got the error.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\Art\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
     */
    public function orWhereNotExists(Closure $callback)
    {
        return $this->orWhereExists($callback, true);
    }

    /**
     * Add an exists clause to the query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query
     * @param  string  $boolean
     * @param  bool  $not
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addWhereExistsQuery(self $query, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
    {
        $type = $not ? 'NotExists' : 'Exists';

        $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');

        $this->addBinding($query->getBindings(), 'where');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Handles dynamic "where" clauses to the query.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $parameters
     * @return $this
     */
    public function dynamicWhere($method, $parameters)
    {
        $finder = substr($method, 5);

        $segments = preg_split(
            '/(And|Or)(?=[A-Z])/', $finder, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
        );
Arguments
"compact(): Undefined variable: operator"
```

The view where this is happening:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="artwork-flexbox">

        <div class="artwork-container">
            <a href='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->image_file_name)}}'>
                <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->image_file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
            </a>
            @foreach($subImages as $subImage)
                <a href='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->image_file_name)}}'>
                    <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$subImage->image_file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>

        <div class="artwork-info-container">

            <p class='author'>
                <a href='{{ route('profile', $author->username)}}'>
                    <img class='profile-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$author->image_file_name)}}'>
                    {{$author->username}}
                </a>
            </p>

            <p class='title'>{{ $image->name }}</p>

            @if(!empty($image->description))
                <p class='description'>{{ $image->description }}</p>
            @endif

            @auth
                <div class="buttons-container">
                    @if ($liked)
                        <button class="submit-btn like liked" id='{{ $image->id }}'><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Liked</button>
                    @else
                        <button class="submit-btn like" id='{{ $image->id }}'><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like</button>
                    @endif
                    @if(Auth::id() === $image->user_id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
                        <a class='edit-btn edit' href="{{ route('updateArtworkView', $image->id) }}"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            @endauth

            <div class="stats-container">
                <p class='likes-count'><i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-fw"></i>{{ $numberOfLikes }} Likes</p>
                <p><i class="far fa-eye fa-fw"></i>{{ $image->views }} Views</p>
                <p class='comments-count'><i class="far fa-comments fa-fw"></i>{{ $commentsCount }} Comments</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-file-download fa-fw"></i>
                    <a href="{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->image_file_name)}}" download="{{ $image->name }}">Download</a>
                </p>
            </div>

            @if(count($tags) > 0)
                <div class='tags-container'>
                    <p><i class="fas fa-tags fa-fw"></i>Tags</p>
                    <div>
                        @foreach($tags as $tag)
                            <a class='image-tag' href="{{url('search?q='.$tag->name)}}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif

            @if(count($recentImages) > 0)
                <p class='more-by-author'>More images by<a href='{{ route('profile', $author->username) }}'>
                    {{ $author->username }}<img class='profile-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$author->image_file_name)}}'>
                </a></p>
                <div class="gallery-container">
                    @foreach($recentImages as $recentImage)
                        <a class="gallery-element" href='{{ route('specificImage', $recentImage->id) }}'>
                            <img class='responsive-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/miniImages/".$recentImage->image_file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                        </a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif

            @if(count($similarImages) > 0)
                <p class='similar-from-category'>Similar images from<a href='{{ route('specificCategory', $image->category->name)}}'>
                    {{ $image->category->name }}<img class='profile-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/categories/thumbnails/".$image->category->image_file_name)}}'>
                </a></p>
                <div class="gallery-container">
                    @foreach($similarImages as $similarImage)
                        <a class="gallery-element" href='{{ route('specificImage', $similarImage->id) }}'>
                            <img class='responsive-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/miniImages/".$similarImage->image_file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                        </a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif

            @auth
                <form class='comment-form' method='POST' action=''>
                    <textarea class='comment-textarea' name='comment'></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="{{ $image->id }}">
                    <button class='submit-btn post-comment' type='submit' name='commentSubmit'><i class="far fa-comment"></i> Comment</button>
                </form>
            @endauth

            @if(count($comments) > 0)
                <div class='comments-container'>
                    @foreach($comments as $comment)
                        <div class="comment-flexbox">
                            <div class="comment-container">
                                <a href='{{ route('profile', $comment->user->username) }}'>
                                    <img class='comment-picture' src='{{ url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$comment->user->image_file_name )}}'>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-info-container">
                                <a href='{{ route('profile', $comment->user->username) }}'>{{ $comment->user->username }}</a>
                                <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-actions-container">
                                @auth
                                    @if(Auth::id() === $comment->user->id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
                                        <i class="fas fa-times delete-comment" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-image="{{ $image->id }}"></i>
                                    @endif
                                @endauth
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif

        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlComment = '{{ route('comment') }}';
    var urlDeleteComment = '{{ route('deleteComment') }}';
    var urlLike = '{{ route('likeArtwork') }}';
</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your controller? And which `laravel/framework` version do you use?

Comment: What's your Laravel version?
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: My Laravel version is 5.5.41, my PHP version is 7.3.7. I'm gonna update my post with view code in a second.

Comment: $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');
there's no $operator

Comment: Where is the variable `$operator`?

Comment: The thing is, the error comes from a Laravel class which I haven't written/altered so I wouldn't know what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried updating `composer`?

Comment: Yes, composer is up to date.

Comment: The solution provided by Amit Senjaliya is definitely bad practice. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555025/how-to-customize-laravels-database-query-builder-make-better-subquery to override the method by extending the default Builder class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because of your php version 7.3 isn’t yet supported.

So I can suggest check following GitHub thread.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936

You can change this file. `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`

From:

```
$this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');
```

To:

```
$this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'query', 'boolean');
```

Comment: Thanks that did solve the issue. Out of curiosity, is it bad practice to alter Laravel files like that?

Comment: Of course it is, every composer update/install will revoke this change, and you will be back at the beginning with the same error. Editing Laravel core files is a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by updating laravel to 5.5.48.