# Laravel Eloquent supporting MariaDb dynamic column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, yii2

For **Dynamic** column supported in **Maria-DB** and in **MySQL** we have JSON column type. For one of our projects, we should be implementing a database for **Maria-DB** (not **Mysql**).

The **Dynamic Column** is supported using [`yii2-dynamic-ar`](https://github.com/tom--/yii2-dynamic-ar) package.

how can can override `Eloquent` orm in `Laravel` to add `dynamic-columns`. in the `Yii` package which added this feature to `ActiveRecord` this classes can override `ActiveRecord` class

implementations classes in `Yii` framework to support in `ActiveRecord` ORM:

1. [DynamicActiveRecord.php](https://github.com/tom--/yii2-dynamic-ar/blob/master/DynamicActiveRecord.php)
2. [DynamicActiveQuery.php](https://github.com/tom--/yii2-dynamic-ar/blob/master/DynamicActiveQuery.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created package for handling MariaDB dynamic Column using eloquent and query builder.

To install package run this command:

```
composer require halalsoft/laravel-dynamic-column
```

You can start using the package by adding the `HasDynamicColumn` trait and use `Dynamic` as attribute cast  to your models.

An example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Halalsoft\LaravelDynamicColumn\Dynamic;
use Halalsoft\LaravelDynamicColumn\HasDynamicColumn;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use HasDynamicColumn;
    protected $casts
        = [
            'the_column' => Dynamic::class,
        ];
}
```

Now You can use dynamic column like json column using eloquent or query builder:

```
$modelData = MyModel::find(1);

$columnData = $modelData->the_column;

$columnData['data1'] = 'value';
$columnData['data2'] = 'value2';


$modelData->the_column = $columnData;

$modelData->save();
```

You can also create data field as array

```
$newData = MyModel::create([
    'other_column' => 'this just another column data',
    'the_column' => ['data1'=>'value1','data2'=>'value2']
]);
```

to update a json field/key you use, you may use the `->` operator when calling the update method:

```
$page->update(['content->data1' => 'value1new']);
```

or you can still update whole column using normal array:

```
$page->update(['content' => ['data1'=>'value1new','data2'=>'value2new']]);
```

You can set as array using other method like `updateOrCreate()`, `firstOrCreate()`,  etc.

This package also support query builder using:

```
Model::query()->where('the_column->data1', 'value1')->first();
```

This package is still new, if any issue or request just go to [github issue](https://github.com/HalalSoft/laravel-dynamic-column/issues)

Comment: thanks a lot, but i think you don't read my question post carefully, because as i said we don't have any problem to using `json` in `maria-db` we want to use `dynamic-column` instead of `json`

Comment: Sorry, I dont know dynamic column, I will figure out it first. thanks

Comment: @DolDurma laravel can handle `dynamic-column` on MariaDB like `json-column` in MySQL, above code is work fine in my case after I read and tried from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/

Comment: yes, that's right, but it doesn't supported with Laravel Eloquent `ORM`, in `Yii` framework a developer, added it to `ActiveResord`

Comment: it's supported as my code written, what do you mean "doesnt support"? it's supported by eloquent?

Comment: the `dynamic-columns` only supported with laravel `Query Builder` to run raw `Sql` commands, not Eloquent `ORM`, you can't use this structure in model because Eloquent doesn't support `MariaDb Dynamic Columns`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228560/discussion-between-doldurma-and-muhammad-dyas-yaskur).

Comment: @DolDurma I updated the answer with package that you were looking for(I hope). Hope it help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can have a cast defined for the column in the Model class

```php
//Model class

protected $casts = ['my_column' => 'array];
```

You can define the datatype for the column as text if you want or json, with the cast defined, you will be able to work with the column data as associative array.

There's also a package to add json datatype in migration for mariadb - it may be of help
https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb