# How to extend default response behaviour after returning Eloquent Model from controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have simple controller which is fetching user from database and returning eloquent object to user.

```
class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        return $user;
    }

}
```

By default Laravel returns JSON. I would like instead to return [RJSON](https://github.com/dogada/RJSON) so I've created following macro

```
Response::macro('rjson', function($collection)
{
    if($collection instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)
    {
        $collection = $collection->toArray();
    }

    $collection = Dmitrirussu\RJson::pack($collection);
    return \Response::make($collection);
});
```

It's working fine but it's inconvenient. I would like to make the same behavior with `return $user` from controller. I tried to extend `json` method in `Respone` Facade without rewarding effect. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Because there is a difference between `return $user;` and `return Response::json($user);`, the first call [toJson method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L718), call `dd(debug_backtrace());` on it to generate a PHP backtrace.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to propose a solution here. Disclaimer here that I have not tested the code, but the approach is very similar to what I'm looking to implement in the next few days (refomatting Eloquent results for Ember.js compatibility).

Basically what [Taylor Otwell (creator of Laravel) suggested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/988#issuecomment-16696585) is:

> Check out the "newCollection" method on the Eloquent\Model class. Override that in a base model and return a custom collection that extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. Then in that Collection extension override the toArray method to format stuff how you want.

So in theory you could do these three steps:

1. Create a subclass of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and override the `toArray()` to do RJSON formatting before returning. Let's say call it `RJsonCollection`.
2. Create a subclass of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to override `newCollection()` method to use your new `RJsonCollection` subclass. Let's say call it `BaseModel`.
3. Convert your models to extend the new `BaseModel`.

Something like this:

**app/models/RJsonCollection.php:**

```php
<?php

class RJsonCollection extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
{
    public function toArray()
    {
        $parentArray = parent::toArray();

        return Dmitrirussu\RJson::pack($parentArray);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming based on your question's code that `Dmitrirussu\RJson::pack($parentArray)` will return a collection/array. You may need to adjust the code above and make sure it returns the proper RJSON array.

**app/models/BaseModel.php:**

```php
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = array())
    {
        return new RJsonCollection($models);
    }
}
```

**app/models/UserModel.php:**

```php
<?php

class UserModel extends BaseModel
{
    // ...
}
```

And of course the usual `composer dump-autoload` and stuff when creating new classes. You may notice that I put all classes above in the models folder and no namespacing. Not the best practices but they do help keeping the example simple and straightforward.

Comment: Nice. You don't need those `use` statements btw. And `BaseModel` also needs custom `toArray()` method in order to fulfill OP's requirement.

Comment: @deczo I learnt that "You need the "use" statement in both files. Use is a file-level keyword and isn't affected by inheritance." from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794901/php-does-extending-class-need-another-use-to-call-namespace, could you re-confirm?

Comment: @deczo for the second part of your comment, I've added a small note of my assumption under RJsonCollection example right about the same time as you commented :p

Comment: About the `use` - it's per file but only if you use those classes in that particular file. Otherwise the deeper in the inheritance hierarchy you get, the longer that list would be. Just check the `Model.php` and any of your model files ;)

Comment: Yup that makes sense. Answer amended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at Fractal's Transformers as a way to create re-usable transformations for your data in a more generic manner:

http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/